# MySQL Select Column if Column in another table is zero

Tags: mysql

My issue is mostly that im not sure how to word what I need in a search.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `accounts`;
+----+--------+---------+----------+
| id | status | oplevel | username |
+----+--------+---------+----------+
| 10 |      1 |       0 | root     |
| 11 |      1 |       1 | Xylex    |
| 12 |      1 |      16 | Anubis   |
| 13 |      0 |      16 | Kami     |
| 14 |      1 |      16 | Zorn     |
+----+--------+---------+----------+


mysql> SELECT * FROM `networks`;
+-----------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+
| networkid | accountid | networkname | serveraddress   |
+-----------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+
|         1 |        10 | Fakenet     | irc.fakenet.org |
|         2 |        10 | Undernet    | irc.under.net   |
|         3 |        12 | Takenet     | irc.takenet.com |
|         4 |        13 | Examplenet  | irc.example.org |
+-----------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+
```

I have this accounts table and this networks table
I need a single query that will return the address of the IRC network, ONLY IF the corresponding account id status column is 1 (enabled)

Ive been searching for hours.
What Do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like a simple join to me:

```
select serveraddress from accounts join networks on id=accountid and id=YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID_HERE
```

Or

```
select serveraddress from networks where accountid=YOUR_ID and exists(select * from accounts where id=accountid and status)
```

Many ways to go about this..

Comment: I need my script to be able to specify the account id

Comment: @user2036369: I've updated the SQL... if you already have the account ID, it's even simpler.

Comment: That querries just this one table though :/

It needs to either return nothing if status in the corresponding id on the accounts table is 0 OR return the server address from networks

Comment: @XylexRayne: Updated again.

Comment: Your second one there Did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the query to place account id.

```
select acc.id, acc.username, nw.serveraddress from accounts acc join networks nw on acc.id = nw.accountid where acc.status == 1 and acc.id=XXX
```

Comment: Forgive me for leaving out a detail...
I need a place to specify the id.

Answer (score 0):

```
select serveraddress from networks, accounts where networks.accountid = accounts.id and accounts.satus=1;
```

Is it what you're looking for?

Comment: Forgive me for leaving out a detail... I need a place to specify the id.